# On removing it selects the item and displays it in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have made a shopping cart and have added a remove button on the items in the cart. So when I press on the remove button the item gets selected and displayed on the screen (in the cart) and then when I refresh the page it gets removed from the page.

[My shopping cart without any changes...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcza5.jpg)

[As I have clicked on remove button of sprite, it has displayed the item on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1s2r.jpg)

[After I refresh my page, Sprite is removed and cart is okay..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlIJ0.jpg)

My function of remove item

```
remove_item = (product, value) => {
    let data = this.state.booth_products;
    let new_array = data.splice(value, 1);
    this.setState({
        booth_products: new_array,
    });
    let edited_product = this.state.cart_data.map((obj) => data || obj);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(edited_product));
};
```

My button code...

```
<button type="button"
className="btn btn-cart-remove"
><i className="ri-close-circle-fill"></i>
<span
onClick={() =>this.remove_item(product,index)}>
Remove
</span>
</button>
```

This is how I am rendering my cart items..

```
<div className="scrollbar-wrap">
{this.state.booth_products.length > 0 ? this.state.booth_products.map(                                                                      
(product,index) => (                                                                          
<div className="product-cart-wrap"                                                                              
key={index}                                                                          
>                                                                              
<div className="img-cover-wrap">                                                                                  
<img                                                                                      
src={product.image} alt={product.name}                                                                                  
/>                                                                              
</div>                                                                              
<div className="product-cart-body-wrap">                                                                                  
<h5 className="text-truncate">                                                                                      
{product.name}                                                                                  
</h5>                                                                                  
<div className="d-center mt-3">                                                                                      
<span className="price-wrap mr-3">                                                                                          
{"$" + product.price}                                                                                      
</span>                                                                                      
<div className="product-count">                                                                                          
<form                                                                                              
action="#" className="display-flex"                                                                                          
>                                                                                              
<div                                                                                                  
className="qtyminus"                                                                                                  
onClick={() => this.decrease_quantity(product,index)}                                                                                              
>                                                                                                  
-                                                                                              
</div>                                                                                              
<input                                                                                                  
type="text" name="quantity" value="1" className="qty"                                                                                                  
value={product.quantity || ""}                                                                                                  
onChange={() =>this.handleChange}                                                                                          
/>                                                                                          
<div                                                                                              
className="qtyplus"                                                                                              
onClick={() =>this.increase_quantity(product,index)}                                                                                          
>                                                                                              
+                                                                                          
</div>                                                                                      
</form>                                                                                  
</div>                                                                                  
<span className="qun-wrap mr-3">                                                                                      
Quantity                                                                   
</span>                                                                                         
<button                                                                                             
type="button" className="btn btn-cart-remove"                                                                                         
>                                                                              
<i className="ri-close-circle-fill"></i>                                                                             
<span                                                                                 
onClick={() =>this.remove_item(product,index)}                                                                                        
>                                                                                            
Remove                                                                                    
</span>                                                                                    
</button>                                                                                
</div>                                                                            
</div>                                                                           
</div>
)
)
: ""}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share how you're rendering your card items?

Comment: @LovleshPokra done please check

Comment: splice modifies the original array and it returns the removed value as output that's why your code was not working. check the working sample in answers block.

Answer (score 0):

following should work for you.

```
remove_item = (product, value) => {
let data = this.state.booth_products;
data.splice(value, 1);
this.setState({
    booth_products: data,
});
let edited_product = this.state.cart_data.map((obj) => data || obj);
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(edited_product));
};
```